# Make RTK Query onCacheEntryAdded return error

Tags: rtk-query

```
// App.tsx
...
export const App: React.FC = () => {
  const { data, error } = useGetUsersQuery()
  
  useEffect(() => {
    console.error(error)
  }, [error])
}
```

```
// api.ts
...
export const api = createApi({
  ...
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    ...
    getUsers: build.query({
      async onCacheEntryAdded(arg, { updateCachedData, cacheDataLoaded, cacheEntryRemoved }) {
        const socket = await getSocket(arg)
        try {
          await cacheDataLoaded
          socket.on("server-error", (message) => {
            updateCachedData((draft, error) => { // There's no error param :(
              error = new Error(message) // Nope.
            })
          })
        } catch (e) {
          console.warn(e)
        }
        ...
      }
    })
  })
})
```

How do I make `onCacheEntryAdded` populate error for the `useGetUsersQuery`?

Comment: It's 2023. Is there any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

check if you import createApi from this directory
`import { createApi } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'`

Comment: I did, thanks. This seems to be a lib problem.